# Add values in combo box from access using VBA ADO connection

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I want to add values in combo box from access using VBA ADO connection. I got the coding from google but it is for account 2003 and below. I have the access 2013 install. Please advise me as to what need to be changed in below coding

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
             "Data Source=C:\Databases\StaffDatabase.mdb"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Department] FROM tblStaff ORDER BY [Department];", _
             cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rst![Department]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work.  You will need to add a reference for the adodb.

In your vba ide you will have to go to dropdown menu tools -> reference and select "Microsoft ActiveX Data Ovjects 2.8 Library"

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of file your Access DB is being saved as. Most have switched over to .accdb filetypes, so if it is, you should be using

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='"
```

Also, make sure you have the Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library referenced

Answer (score 0):

You need the `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider, and using `AddItem` is quite slow. I suggest:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=C:\Databases\StaffDatabase.mdb"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Department] FROM tblStaff ORDER BY [Department];", _
             cnn, adOpenStatic
    Me.ComboBox1.Column = rst.GetRows

UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```